# Keep Shared Preferences even the application package of android have been uninstall in offline mode

Tags: android, performance, storage, uninstallation, android-sharedpreferences

I found out the backup can restored the shared preferences after the application been uninstall, just wondering is there anyway to keep SharedPreferences in device even the application have been uninstall in offline mode?

Comment: Yes you can do it. While creating SharedPreferences declare MODE as WORLD_READABLE. it will solve your problem

Comment: well, is not working on my side. By the way I wanna stored private message in the mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by Google's backup service. If you wanted to do it by yourself.

Several choice for you:

```
1. Store the data on line by yourself.
2. Store the data on SDCARD
```

And some more information: uninstall the APK will not cause the data to be removed immediately.